# Preventing container resize on click

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to figure out how to fix this quirk:

When clicking on the left arrow, the text and right arrow get pushed to the right a little: http://jsfiddle.net/E72dz/

Any idea on how to fix this? I guess making the span around the text a specific width, but that kind of introduces other issues when added.

Comment: Setting a width on the text's parent and probably setting it to `text-align: center` is likely the most straightforward solution. But you don't want to do that?

Comment: "kind of introduces other issues"? What kind of issues? You may have a little extra space around "1" than "100", but how wide do you expect the text to possibly get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said yourself, I believe it's best to simply set a fixed width, by adding this to your CSS:

```
span.meta.prel {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

As per [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jblasco/HeDEz/). It seems like the most straightforward solution to me, and doesn't seem to have any other huge effects on your layout (which I do think is a little bizarre in itself).

On a side note, I don't think causing a container's size to increase by adding content to it should really be considered a "quirk."

Answer (score 1):

Seems obvious that it's the difference between the space needed for the single digit 9 and the space needed for the double digit 10. Note no change in this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E72dz/2/).

If you don't want to use leading 0s fo the single digits you could set the width to a fixed width like [this updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/E72dz/3/)

Comment: Wish I could accept both. Upvote for you. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Its not that its pushing the text over, it's adding a whole new character when it jumps from 9 to 10. If you don't have a specific width set it adds it for that character, if you don't want to include the width you could include 0 placeholders to fill that. If its pulled in dynamically I would recommend using that language to format the string to include leading 0's